# What does this popup mean, "New Location Detected", what application is displaying it?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

[image]

I get this popup on my Macbook Pro High Sierra 10.13.6.

There is no title bar.  When I click on the popup it does not become selected and the "current application" in the Mac menu remains whatever it was.

How can I tell what application is displaying this popup?   How can I tell what it means?   What is a "location" -- is this a GPS thing, a network thing (wifi?  Bluetooth?), is it from Maps?   Has my Mac discovered new unknown lands and expanded the horizons of mankind?   How am I supposed to know?   What if I Add?  What if I Decline?   What happens in either case?   Am I  like Kyle in Human Centipad?

Comment: That's not a system dialog; which eliminates it being the OS itself or any Apple app, if not what it might actually be - but it at least narrows it down to apps you have installed which are location-aware.

Comment: Thank you.   On Microsoft Windows, when I had a "mystery popup" like this, my cheap trick was to grab it and move it around frantically while watching the process monitor.     The offending process would move up the CPU% rankings, usually close enough to the top that I could see it.     I've never needed to do that on my Mac, and this particular window has no title bar and cannot be grabbed or moved anyway.   It's useful to know it's not a system dialog, and it does indeed narrow it down .... but not very much.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, I get this too; it is from Jabber.
[image]

If I click on the popup, Jabber appeared in the menu bar.  I think Preferences->Locations controls it.

Comment: Thank you!  When I click on the popup nothing happens, but I started using Jabber a couple of months ago, this must be it.  Now I can try to fix it.  Thanks.